# MapThread over a list of sublists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mapthread

I am trying to plot a list of two sublists, each of length 5 to produce two curves:

```
aaa = {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}};
imax = 5;
```

I tried two ways to no avail. These are:

```
MapThread[ListPlot[Transpose[{i, {i, 1, imax}, #}]]][
  aaa[[j]], {j, 1, imax}];

MapThread[ListPlot[Transpose[{i, {i, 1, imax}, aaa[[#]]}]]][j, {j, 1, 
  imax}]
```

Both attempts were ruled erroneous. Your help would be appreciated.

### Edit

A short version of the list looks like the following:

```
{{552.792, 6.28145, 1.51948, 0.905935, 0.725876, 0.422672, 0.443358,
0.270075, 0.304024, 0.195848, 0.222525, 0.1511, 0.169572, 0.1206,
0.13256, 0.098111, 0.105207, 0.0805748, 0.0840317},{0.0662868, 0.0669424, 0.0541982, 0.0525879, 0.0436082, 0.0400327,
0.0340136, 0.0285805, 0.0250322, 0.0176771, 0.0163611, 0.0069072,
0.00756966, 0.00458268, 0.0144777, 2.00194, 3.82806, 7.9682, 24.8342}}
```

The goal is to produce two curves with these two sublists as the ordinate values of these two curves.

For the abscissa, it is a simple, equal spaced sequence, specifically,

```
{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4,
1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9}
```

I hope this clarifies the problem.

Comment: does this give what you are trying to get: `ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Range[imax], #}] & /@ aaa,  PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`?

Comment: If what kglr suggests gives you what you want then you may also be interested in `ListLinePlot[aaa]`.

Comment: or, simply, `ListLinePlot[aaa, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,  PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, All}]`

Comment: These various applications of ListLinePlot did not work. Perhaps, I made the wrong impression by suggesting the aaa represents two straight line. The List aaa is meant to be two sublists of arbitrary numbers, not necessarily straight lines.

Comment: `ListPlot[{{0, 1, 4, 9, 16}, {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}}, Joined -> True]`

Comment: `ListPlot[{{0, 1, 4, 9, 16}, {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5}}, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All]`

Comment: Since you have said the suggestions did not work, suppose `aaa = {{0,1,3,6,10},{5,6,9,14,21}}` Can you write by hand the list of (x,y) points from aaa that you want in each of your two curves? Perhaps then someone can understand how to do what you want.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[aaa]` should simply do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
aaa = {{552.792, 6.28145, 1.51948, 0.905935, 0.725876, 0.422672, 
    0.443358, 0.270075, 0.304024, 0.195848, 0.222525, 0.1511, 
    0.169572, 0.1206, 0.13256, 0.098111, 0.105207, 0.0805748, 0.0840317}, 
   {0.0662868, 0.0669424, 0.0541982, 0.0525879, 
    0.0436082, 0.0400327, 0.0340136, 0.0285805, 0.0250322, 0.0176771, 
    0.0163611, 0.0069072, 0.00756966, 0.00458268, 0.0144777, 2.00194, 
    3.82806, 7.9682, 24.8342}};
```

**1.** You can use the option `DataRange -> {.1, 1.9}`:

```
ListLinePlot[aaa, DataRange -> {.1, 1.9}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> False]
```

[image]

You can add the option `PlotRange -> All` to get

[image]

Better yet, add the option `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}` (or use `ListLogPlot`  instead of `ListLinePlot` as suggested by Okkes) :

```
ListLinePlot[aaa, DataRange -> {.1, 1.9}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `MapIndexed` to add the x coordinates:

```
ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]]/10, #} &] /@ aaa, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> False]
```

[image]

**3.**  Create a list of x coordinates and combine it with `aaa` using `Transpose` ( or `Thread`):

```
xxx = Range[Length[aaa[[1]]]] / 10;

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xxx, #}] & /@ aaa, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 ClippingStyle -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your showing example data was very helpful. Thank you

Try

```
aaa={{552.792, 6.28145, 1.51948, 0.905935, 0.725876, 0.422672, 0.443358,0.270075, 0.304024,
0.195848,0.222525, 0.1511, 0.169572, 0.1206,0.13256, 0.098111, 0.105207, 0.0805748, 0.0840317},
{0.0662868, 0.0669424, 0.0541982, 0.0525879, 0.0436082, 0.0400327,0.0340136, 0.0285805, 0.0250322,
0.0176771, 0.0163611, 0.0069072,0.00756966, 0.00458268, 0.0144777, 2.00194, 3.82806, 7.9682, 24.8342}};
abscissa=Range[1/10,19/10,1/10];(* use exact rationals to ensure correct number of entries*)
Show[
  ListPlot[Transpose[{abscissa,aaa[[1]]}],Joined->True],
  ListPlot[Transpose[{abscissa,aaa[[2]]}],Joined->True]]
```

or

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{abscissa,aaa[[1]]}],Transpose[{abscissa,aaa[[2]]}]},Joined->True]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{abscissa,aaa[[1]]}],Transpose[{abscissa,aaa[[2]]}]}]
```

or, since you asked to use `Map`

```
ListPlot[Map[Transpose[{abscissa,#}]&,aaa],Joined->True]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[Map[Transpose[{abscissa,#}]&,aaa]]
```

Please test this carefully to make certain I have made no mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ListLogPlot`  might be more meaningful here.

```
data = {{552.792, 6.28145, 1.51948, 0.905935, 0.725876, 0.422672, 
        0.443358, 0.270075, 0.304024, 0.195848, 0.222525, 0.1511, 
        0.169572, 0.1206, 0.13256, 0.098111, 0.105207, 0.0805748, 
        0.0840317}, {0.0662868, 0.0669424, 0.0541982, 0.0525879, 
        0.0436082, 0.0400327, 0.0340136, 0.0285805, 0.0250322, 0.0176771, 
        0.0163611, 0.0069072, 0.00756966, 0.00458268, 0.0144777, 2.00194, 
        3.82806, 7.9682, 24.8342}};

ListLogPlot[Transpose[{Range[0.1, 1.9, 0.1], #}] & /@ data, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
xvals = Range[0.1, 1.9, 0.1];
yvals = {{552.792, 6.28145, 1.51948, 0.905935, 0.725876, 0.422672, 
   0.443358, 0.270075, 0.304024, 0.195848, 0.222525, 0.1511, 0.169572,
    0.1206, 0.13256, 0.098111, 0.105207, 0.0805748, 
   0.0840317}, {0.0662868, 0.0669424, 0.0541982, 0.0525879, 0.0436082,
    0.0400327, 0.0340136, 0.0285805, 0.0250322, 0.0176771, 0.0163611, 
   0.0069072, 0.00756966, 0.00458268, 0.0144777, 2.00194, 3.82806, 
   7.9682, 24.8342}};
```

Any of the following can be used, the most familiar being the last one:

```
data = Thread[{xvals, #}] & /@ yvals
data2 = MapThread[List, {xvals, #}] & /@ yvals
data3 = Transpose[{xvals, #}] & /@ yvals
```

> {{{0.1, 552.792}, {0.2, 6.28145}, {0.3, 1.51948}, {0.4,
> 0.905935}, {0.5, 0.725876}, {0.6, 0.422672}, {0.7, 0.443358}, {0.8,
> 0.270075}, {0.9, 0.304024}, {1., 0.195848}, {1.1, 0.222525}, {1.2,
> 0.1511}, {1.3, 0.169572}, {1.4, 0.1206}, {1.5, 0.13256}, {1.6,
> 0.098111}, {1.7, 0.105207}, {1.8, 0.0805748}, {1.9,
> 0.0840317}}, {{0.1, 0.0662868}, {0.2, 0.0669424}, {0.3,
> 0.0541982}, {0.4, 0.0525879}, {0.5, 0.0436082}, {0.6,
> 0.0400327}, {0.7, 0.0340136}, {0.8, 0.0285805}, {0.9,
> 0.0250322}, {1., 0.0176771}, {1.1, 0.0163611}, {1.2,
> 0.0069072}, {1.3, 0.00756966}, {1.4, 0.00458268}, {1.5,
> 0.0144777}, {1.6, 2.00194}, {1.7, 3.82806}, {1.8, 7.9682}, {1.9,
> 24.8342}}}

```
ListLinePlot[data, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]